# (property) UsersComponent.users: UserDataList[] Type 'UserData' is missing the following properties from type 'UserDataList[]': length, pop, push

Tags: angular, api

I'm assigning users variable to the UserDataList array. But it's giving error while assigning. Here is the code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserDataList } from '../models/api-models/users.model';
import { UserData } from '../models/ui-models/users.model';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit{
  users: UserDataList[]=[];

  constructor(private userService:UserService){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    //Fetch Users
    this.userService.getAllUsers()
    .subscribe(
      (successResponse)=>{
        //console.log(successResponse.data[0].OrgName);
        // console.log(successResponse[1].State);
        this.users= successResponse;
      },
    (errorResponse)=>{
      console.log(errorResponse);
    }

    )

  }

}
```

What am I doing wrong in this code?

Can you help me with this?

This is the model which is designed:-

```
export interface UserData {
    IsSuccess: string,
    Message: string,
    data: UserDataList[]
  }
  
  export interface UserDataList {
    Id: string,
    CreatedDate: string,
    UpdatedDate: string,
    OrgName: string,
    Address: string,
    State: string,
    Country: string,
    City: string,
    ZipCode: number,
    EmailId: string,
    Website: string,
    PrimaryContact: string,
    PrimaryContactMobile: string,
    SecondaryContact: string,
    SecondaryContactMobile: string,
    Programs: string,
    Status: string
  }
```

I have also tried doing

```
users: UserData["data"]=[];
```

But its' not working either. Please help me with this.

Comment: `this.users = successResponse.data`

Answer (score 0):

If *successResponse* is a correct data, try:

```
    this.users = <UserDataList[]>successResponse;
```